# В каком TU генерируется виртуальная таблица, если функции inline?

Tags: c++, классы, gcc, virtual

В каком/каких TU генерируется vtable для класса, содержащего только `inline` виртуальные функции?

Например, есть хедер `S.h`:

```
struct S {
  virtual foo() {}
};
```

И несколько компилируемых файлов `A.cpp`, `B.cpp`, которые включают этот хедер. В каком TU будет сгенерирован vtable?

Comment: это проблема компилятора. Стандарт не требует даже vtable. Где будет таблица (если она будет)? В всех скомпилированных файлах. Потом линковщик будет зачищать.

Comment: @KoVadim вопрос для компилятора `gcc`

Comment: а это не имеет значения.

Comment: @KoVadim не имеет значения компилятор или положение таблицы?

Comment: где будет создан объект

Comment: Компилятор. Если он реализовывает vtable, то он вынужден будет складывать ее в каждый файл. Или компилировать файл за файлом (в одно ядро!) или обладать телепатией. А с какой целью Вы интересуетесь?

Comment: @KoVadim "складывать ее в каждый файл" конкретно в данном случае или всегда при наличии виртуальных функций? Интересуюсь для оптимизации размера бинарников и объектников

Comment: @ARHovsepyan хотите сказать, что если в `A.cpp` есть просто определение класса `S`, но нет создания его объекта, то vtable не будет генерироваться?

Comment: наличие или отсутствие виртуальных функций не есть поводом делать vtable. Поэтому, включение файла с таким классом ещё не повод делать vtable. Компилятор может сделать оптимизацию.

Comment: Именно. А как генерировать, если не известно еще какова она?  Если в другой единице будет определен производный класс и создан объект как до этого создать виртуальную таблицу?  Разные компиляторы, как сказано выше, это могут делать по разному. Вам это не должно заинтересовать. Ничего это вам не даст.

Comment: нет проблем сгенерировать vtable, для этого не нужно знать всех наследников.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan в другой единице она просто будет своя (больше). Это не повод выдавать ошибки для не максимально глубоких иерархий. Т.е. таблица не одна на всех максимально большая, а минимально необходимая для данного TU, в моём понимании

Comment: @jason, но если вы знаете, тогда зачем спрашивать?  А я знаю, что компиляторы не так глупы, чтобы создавать что то, для чего нет нужды. Кстати компилятор вполне имеет право вообще не создавать таблицу  оставляя это компановщику.

Comment: Если таблицы будут разные по размеру, то это может привести к большим проблемам, если будет "вызов через границу единицы компиляции". Поэтому они будут одинаковые

Comment: @KoVadim как они могут быть одинаковые? Например, 1 TU содержит только базовый класс, имеющий 1 реализацию виртуальной функции, а другой - 10 наследников, каждый со своей реализацией. Как при компиляции только первого TU понять одинаковый размер? Или это происходит позже?

Comment: вирутальная таблица класса не зависит от его наследников.

Comment: @KoVadim я не понимаю. Если есть время, объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее в ответе, когда и где генерируется vtable при наличии у класса только виртуальных inline функций в `gcc`, зависит ли это от inline и наличия объектов этого класса

Comment: я уже написал все. Это очень зависит от конкретных версий компилятора, а не только от просто компилятора. Если Вы боитесь, что виртуальные функции раздувают Ваш код - не используйте виртуальные функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vtable генерируется в конечном бинаре, при условии, что класс там использован таким образом, что в ней появляется необходимость, т.е. когда реально присутствуют неоптимизированные вызовы его виртуальных функций. Современные компиляторы производят кодогенерацию оптимизированного кода не при создании TU, а потом, когда происходит линковка этих TU в бинарь.

Comment: Учитывая, что я это все уже написал...

Comment: На этапе создания объектных файлов происходит какое-либо взаимодействие с vtable? Т.е. я правильно понимаю, что сначала компилятор делает разные vtable для каждого TU в данном случае, а потом при линковке оставляет одну, если был хотя бы один неоптимизированный вызов? Или же вообще он никаких не реагирует на виртуальные функции и всё происходит после генерации объектников? Мне надо оптимизировать также размер объектников, поэтому интересует это

Comment: он не делает разные таблицы.

Comment: @jason Нет, компилятор делает vtable только в бинаре. В TU содержится внутреннее представление собранного кода (которое может быть очень разным у разных компиляторов или даже у одинаковых, но с разными настройками сборки). Хотя когда-то оно возможно действительно совпадало с тем, что потом попадало в бинарь.

Comment: Меня смущает то, что в [документации gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_vtable) говорится про генерацию vtable в одном/нескольких объектных файлах -- *Whenever possible the vtable will only be generated and output in a single object file rather than generating the vtable in every object file which refers to the class*. То, что в итоге останется только 1, - это хорошо для бинаря, но интересно, можно ли уменьшить размер объектников, оставив хотя бы одну key function

Comment: @jason Чтобы уменьшить размер объектников не следует использовать больше одного, ака SKU.

Comment: в документации сказано то, что я говорил - когда возможно, компилятор пытается не генерировать. Но это внутренние дела компилятора.

Answer (score 0):

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_vtable

> Every polymorphic class requires a virtual table or vtable describing
> the type and its virtual functions. **Whenever possible the vtable will
> only be generated and output in a single object file rather than
> generating the vtable in every object file which refers to the class**
> (which might be hundreds of objects that include a header but don't
> actually use the class.) The cross-platform C++ ABI states that the
> vtable will be output in the object file that contains the definition
> of the key function, which is defined as the first **non-inline**,
> non-pure, virtual function declared in the class. If you do not
> provide a definition for the key function (or fail to link to the file
> providing the definition) then the linker will not be able to find the
> class' vtable.

https://lld.llvm.org/missingkeyfunction.html#missing-key-function

> **When a class has a key function, the compiler emits the vtable (and
> some other things as well) only in the translation unit that defines
> that key function.** Thus, if you’re missing the key function, you’ll
> also be missing the vtable. If no other function calls your missing
> function, you won’t see any undefined reference errors for it, but you
> will see undefined references to the vtable symbol.
>
> When a class has no non-pure, non-inline, virtual functions, there is
> no key function, and the compiler **is forced to emit the vtable in
> every translation unit that references the class**. In this case, it is
> emitted in a COMDAT section, which allows the linker to eliminate all
> duplicate copies. **This is still wasteful in terms of object file size
> and link time, so it’s always advisable to ensure there is at least
> one eligible function that can serve as the key function**.